# Как реализовать создание папки и сохранении в неё файла с именем из текста в файле

Tags: vba

Суть задачи такова: есть смета которую выводит программа, в содержимом сметы есть номер данной сметы который выглядит типа 00-00-0-00-00, этот номер всегда находится в одной ячейке с текстом и может выглядеть в 3 вариантах: ЛОКАЛЬНЫЙ СМЕТНЫЙ РАСЧЕТ № 00-00-0-00-00, либо СМЕТНЫЙ РАСЧЕТ № 00-00-0-00-00, либо ЛОКАЛЬНАЯ СМЕТА № 00-00-0-00-00. Нужно вычленить номер расчёта обозвать им Лист, затем отнять от номера расчёта 3 последних символа - это будет номер Объекта типа(00-00-0-00), под номером объекта создать папку на рабочем столе и сохранить в неё  файл по именем номера  расчёта типа(00-00-0-00-00). Нижеприведённый код с этим прекрасно справлялся, пока к номеру не добавили текст означающий корректировку Кn типа(00-00-0-00-00 Кn), где n - номер корректировки, всегда однозначное число, т.е. максимум К9, и Иn - всё тоже самое только И - изменение. Я уже голову сломал, как это реализовать.

```
Sub xxx ()
    Dim НомерОбъекта As String
    Dim НомерЛокального As String

    If Cells.Find(What:="СМЕТНЫЙ РАСЧЕТ № ", After:=ActiveCell, LookIn:=xlFormulas, _
    LookAt:=xlPart, SearchOrder:=xlByRows, SearchDirection:=xlNext, _
    MatchCase:=False, SearchFormat:=False) Is Nothing Then
    If MsgBox("Отсутствует фраза _СМЕТНЫЙ РАСЧЕТ №_. Макрос будет прерван!", vbCritical + vbOKOnly) = vbOK Then
        End
        Else
        End If
    Else
    НомерЛокального = Right(Cells.Find(What:="СМЕТНЫЙ РАСЧЕТ № ", After:=ActiveCell, LookIn:=xlFormulas, _
    LookAt:=xlPart, SearchOrder:=xlByRows, SearchDirection:=xlNext, _
    MatchCase:=False, SearchFormat:=False), 13)
    Range("C1") = НомерЛокального
    НомерОбъекта = Mid(НомерЛокального, 1, 10)
    Range("C2") = НомерОбъекта
    ActiveSheet.Name = НомерЛокального
    folder = CreateObject("WScript.Shell").SpecialFolders("Desktop") & "\" & НомерОбъекта & "\" 
    On Error Resume Next: MkDir folder
    ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs folder & НомерЛокального & ".xls"
    Application.CutCopyMode = False ' очищение буфера обмена
    End If

End Sub
```

Comment: не совсем понятен вопрос. 1.Кn либо Иn добавляются к номеру всегда? 2. Название листа и файла должно быть таким же, как и было раньше?

Comment: Нет, не всегда, в том и подвох. Название листа, файла и папки должно соответствовать номеру из сметы, если он с буквой К, то есть смета была откорректирована первый раз и к её номеру добавили К1.  Между номером и К1 строго должен стоят пробел.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

В качестве решения можно проверять третий слева символ на равенство пробелу, и уже исходя из этого выделять номер.

Чтобы не использовать лишних ветвлений для создания имени файла, можно воспользоваться особенностью функции `mid`, что если значение параметра `start` больше длины строки, то возвращается пустая строка, и если не указывать параметр `length`, то выбираются все символы до конца строки.

Также вместо использования символа косой черты при создании пути лучше использовать `Application.PathSeparator`. Привожу код с минимальными изменениями.

```
Sub xxx ()
    Dim НомерОбъекта As String
    Dim НомерЛокального As String
    Dim ЯчейкаНомера As Range
    Dim ЗнаковВНомере As Integer

    Set ЯчейкаНомера = Cells.Find(What:="СМЕТНЫЙ РАСЧЕТ № ", After:=ActiveCell, LookIn:=xlFormulas, _
            LookAt:=xlPart, SearchOrder:=xlByRows, SearchDirection:=xlNext, _
            MatchCase:=False, SearchFormat:=False)
    If  ЯчейкаНомера Is Nothing Then
        MsgBox "Отсутствует фраза _СМЕТНЫЙ РАСЧЕТ №_. Макрос будет прерван!", vbCritical + vbOKOnly
        End
    Else
        ЗнаковВНомере = IIf(Mid(ЯчейкаНомера.Value, Len(ЯчейкаНомера.Value) - 2, 1) = " ", 16, 13)
        НомерЛокального = Right(ЯчейкаНомера.Value, ЗнаковВНомере)
        НомерОбъекта = Mid(НомерЛокального, 1, 10) & Mid(НомерЛокального, 14)
        ActiveSheet.Name = НомерЛокального
        folder = CreateObject("WScript.Shell").SpecialFolders("Desktop") & Application.PathSeparator & НомерОбъекта & Application.PathSeparator
        On Error Resume Next: MkDir folder
        ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs folder & НомерЛокального & ".xls"
        Application.CutCopyMode = False
        Set ЯчейкаНомера = Nothing
    End If

End Sub
```

Comment: Эдуард спасибо вам за идею - она сработала(смотрите мой ответ на собственный вопрос), но именно этот ваш код не работает, либо вы меня до конца не поняли(что я хочу).

Comment: @ДмитрийКутыркин понял Ваши желания, поправил код. Вроде теперь всё как нужно.

Comment: Да теперь код работает как нужно и намного более лаконичный, чем мой, спасибо!

Comment: Эдуард найдите меня по фамилии и городу ВКонтакте. у меня к вам вопросы.

Comment: @ДмитрийКутыркин в соцсетях не вожусь. можете спросить в чате http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/54694/

Answer (score 0):

Непонятна проблема. Возможно, пробел в имени файла мешает (вряд ли...). Попробуйте заменить на "_". Больше явных причин не видно.

Несколько замечаний по коду.

Имена переменных. Да, они должны "рассказывать", за что отвечают. Но слишком длинные имена затрудняют чтение кода.

Не используйте в качестве имен зарезервированные слова, это может привести к неприятностям.

Папки можно создавать без применения *CreateObject*:

```
Dim sPathFldr As String
        sPathFldr = ThisWorkbook.Path & "\НомерОбъекта\" ' путь к папке
        If Dir(sPathFldr, vbDirectory) = "" Then MkDir sPathFldr ' создаем, если нет
```

Comment: Как быть если пробел должен стоять строго, добавлять его каким-то образом впоследствии? Тут ещё загвоздка в чём, я Right-ом отсчитываю 13 символов справа(т.к. номер сметы строго 13 символов), а если смета с корректировкой К1 допустим, то добавляются ещё 3 символа, и отсчитав 13 получаю ерунду, если поставить с запасом 16, то потом надо удалял текст который попадёт в последние символы, если номер без К1.

Comment: Если есть *К*, то 16, иначе 13

Comment: т.к. иногда вместо К может быть И, то мне кажется проще проверить 3й справа символ на равенство пробелу

Comment: если номер будет без К и И, третий символ справа ТОЖЕ будет пробел!

Comment: @ДмитрийКутыркин почему пробел? Дефис там.

Comment: Верно Эдуард, моя ошибаться. Получается ваш метод состоит в том, чтобы я записал в некую переменную третий символ справа и если он равен пробелу отсчитывал 16 символов, если тире то 13. По-моему сработает:)

Comment: Я понял так, что в имя файла добавляли Кn (Иn) и это вызывало ошибку. Ясно теперь...